# How to connect two Juniper gns3 with fastethernet?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, gns3

I need to connect two Juniper routers with fastethernet interface. When I am connected by em0, I can check the connection between them by ping. But when I tried to set fe-0/0/0 in two routers, I can't ping them. I see this message: `ping: sendto: No route to host`. How to fix this?

My first router config is this:

```
fe-1/0/0 {
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address 192.168.1.2/24;
    }
}
em1 {
description R1;
vlan-tagging;
unit 0 {
    vlan-id 10;
    family inet {
        address 192.168.10.1/30;
    }
}
```

And the second is this:

```
fe-1/0/0 {
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        address 192.168.1.1/24;
    }
}
em1 {
description R2;
vlan-tagging;
unit 0 {
    vlan-id 10;
    family inet {
        address 192.168.10.2/30;
    }
}
```

The symptom:

```
root> ping 192.168.10.2
PING 192.168.10.2 (192.168.10.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.10.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=16.168 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.968 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.244 ms
^Z
Suspended
root@% ping 192.168.1.2
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include your configurations.

Comment: Please, never post text as an image. Just copy the text, paste it into the question, and use the Preformatted text feature (`{}`).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `em` interfaces are the only usable interfaces on an Olive (Junos emulator). Although Junos will let you configure other interfaces, they will not show up, nor will the prefixes you assign to them be installed in the routing table.

You can easily check this for yourself :

Configuring three interfaces on an emulated Juniper :

```
root> show configuration interfaces | display set 
set interfaces fe-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 10.10.10.1/30
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 10.10.99.1/30
set interfaces em0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.99.1/30

root>
```

Check your interfaces - the (Fast/Gigabit) ethernet interfaces do not show up :

```
root> show interfaces terse 
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
cbp0                    up    up 
demux0                  up    up 
dsc                     up    up 
em0                     up    up 
em0.0                   up    up   inet     192.168.99.1/30 
em1                     up    up 
em2                     up    up 
em3                     up    up 
gre                     up    up 
<...>
```

Same goes for your routing table :

```
root> show route 

inet.0: 2 destinations, 2 routes (2 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both 
192.168.99.0/30    *[Direct/0] 00:12:13
                    > via em0.0
192.168.99.1/32    *[Local/0] 00:12:13
                      Local via em0.0

root>
```

Please note that this behaviour (the ability of creating configurations for non-existing interfaces) mimicks the behaviour of 'real' Juniper routers (which makes sense, because an Olive is an emulator) : In real life, you will also be able to prepare and commit your configurations, for example prior to inserting a new linecard.